# Using fp-ts sequenceS on Eithers with different left types

Tags: typescript, either, fp-ts

I want to use sequenceS function but it does not correctly infer left types. Let's consider the following code:

```js
declare function validateEmail(
  email: string
): E.Either<EmailValidationError, Email>
declare function validateUsername(
  username: string
): E.Either<UsernameValidationError, Email>

function validateData(inputs: {
  email: string
  username: string
}) {
  return sequenceS(E.Apply)({
    email: validateEmail(inputs.email),
    username: validateUsername(inputs.username),
  })
}
```

I get a following error: `Type 'UsernameValidationError' is not assignable to type 'EmailValidationError'.`

I know I can fix it by specifying the types explicitly like so:

```js
function validateData(inputs: {email: string; username: string}) {
  return sequenceS(E.Apply as apply.Apply2C<
    'Either', UsernameValidationError | EmailValidationError
  >)({
    email: validateEmail(inputs.email),
    username: validateUsername(inputs.username),
  })
}
```

But that does not seem practical especially with big objects created this way.
I can also use dot notation but that still leaves me wandering if I am doing something wrong with this sequenceS use. Is there a way how to tell typescript to automatically infer the left types?

Comment: It's probably easier to use Do notation with apS/apSW instead of sequenceS. See this comment here: https://github.com/gcanti/fp-ts/issues/1568#issuecomment-919974527

Answer (score 0):

For how `sequenceS` is defined it expects values with fixed types on `Left`. For your use case you can use [`Do` notation](https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/guides/do-notation.html).

```js
function validateData(inputs: {
  email: string
  username: string
}) {
  return pipe(
    validateEmail(inputs.email),
    E.bindTo('email'),
    E.apSW('username', validateUsername(inputs.username),
  )
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know the dot notation is possible (see the last paragraph of my question). I just wanted to know, if I can also use sequenceS. 

But it's no big deal. I will eventually move to effect-ts since they will release stable version very soon :).